# How to keep multiple render_template() of different forms in one page

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to design a webpage with flask in python.

The web first asks the user to enter their name, then submit this form to result() function (for short, it just returns the form by render_template()), and then shows the result on the same page below.

After that, based on the above result, I want to submit a second form and show both returns on this page. But after submitting the second form, the first result will be empty. How can I store the first return after submitting the second form?

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "/result" method = ["POST", "GET"]>
         <p>First Name<input type = "text" name = "FirstName" /></p>
         <p>Last Name<input type = "text" name = "LastName" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
      {% if result or func%}
      <p> Result is {{result}} </p>
      <form action = "/func" method = ["POST", "GET"]>
          <p>Addition Info 1<input type = "text" name = "Info1" /></p>
          <p>Addition Info 2<input type = "text" name = "Info2" /></p>
          <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
          {% if func%}
          <p> Result is {{func}} </p>
          {% endif %}
      </form>
      {% endif %}
   </body>
</html>
```

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)

@app.route('/func',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def func():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      func= request.form
      return render_template("result.html",func= func)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 ways of doing this

1. Use `Ajax` to submit the forms. Using `Ajax` means the page is not reloaded (so whatever user has entered in the page is still visible). But it means you have to use Javascript to handle what `result` or `func` returns.
2. Capture the output from `result` as an attribute in the second form and pass it back to your backend when you submit the second form. This way you have both `result` and `func` and then you also return both of them.